# Search all StackExchange Sites

Tags: discussion, search

How do I use the search on AskDifferent to search all stackexchange sites.

Example: I have a question and would like to know if an answer exists in here or on StackOwerflow, Meta StackOwerflow...ect...

I know how to use Google, and how to switch the sites, but wondering if there is time saving approach within the AskDifferent.

Comment: Google usually works the best. Joel Spolsky has said that Google is the basically the home page for Stack Exchange (paraphrasing). Also, this question would be better on a meta site, so a moderator may close or move it, FYI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

http://stackexchange.com/search

Comment: great answer :)